# How to get extract/compress option on right clicking?

Tags: linux-mint, mouse, nautilus, zip, rar

I am using Linux Mint 14 Nadia . Earlier whenever I right  clicked any folder I got options like Extract it, Compress etc. But now I am not getting them . Probably I changed/deleted some of the utilities . I have nautilus installed on my system . Is there any way I can get those 2 features back in the options list when I right click any folder ?

Comment: I have file roller installed already

Comment: Do you have engrampa installed? This looks to be the fork of file-roller. http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=101731#p577628

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Linux Mint Forum I found the following post, [Extract, Compress in right-click menu](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=105332). According to that post you have 2 options:

- Use Caja instead of Nautilus (I believe Caja is just a fork of Nautilus)
- Install File Roller + xarchiver

According to that post these are the steps required to install File Roller:

1. open synaptic manager
2. search for file roller
3. select file roller to install
4. search for xarchiver
5. select xarchiver to install
6. restart

Comment: I tried it already but to no use... :(

Comment: Can you also try installing xarchiver. Just came across this blog post: http://mayukhmukherjee.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/adding-archive-utilities-to-gnome-3-context-menu/

Comment: I tried it also ...

Comment: Glad that worked!

Comment: apt-get install xarchiver file-roller

Answer (score 7):

Didn't work for me on XFCE Linux Mint 13 with Caja. But what did work finally was:

```
$ sudo apt-get install engrampa
```

then:

```
$ pkill caja
```

Caja then restarted itself and afterwards within the last entries there is a "compress" option.

*Source: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=110&t=116033*

Answer (score 1):

Install `file-roller` and `xarchiver`. It works for me.